# Maintaining checkbox state in jQuery accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a nested accordion with a checkbox that makes an ajax call if checked, the problem is that the checkbox does not remain checked after the accordion expands.

```
if (childList.length > 0) {

                list += '<ul class = ui-accordion>';
                for (var j = 0; j < childList.length; j++) {

                    list += '<li><div><a href="#"><input type = "checkbox" class = "reqCheckBox" value="' + childList[i].ComponentID + '"/> ' + childList[j].ComponentDesc +'</a></div>';

                    var grandChildList = $.grep(data, function (n, k) {
                        return n.ParentID == childList[j].ComponentID;
                    }, false);

                    if (grandChildList.length > 0) {

                        list += '<ul class = ui-accordion>';


                        for (var k = 0; k < grandChildList.length; k++) {
                            list += '<li><div><a href="#"><input type = "checkbox" onclick="getReq(' + grandChildList[i].ComponentID + ')"/>' + grandChildList[k].ComponentDesc + '</a></div>';

                            var greatGrandChildList = $.grep(data, function (n, l) {
                                return n.ParentID == grandChildList[k].ComponentID;
                            }, false);

                            if (greatGrandChildList.length > 0) {

                                list += '<ul class = ui-accordion>';

                                for (var l = 0; l < greatGrandChildList.length; l++) {
                                    list += '<li><div><a href="#"><input type = "checkbox" onclick="getReq(' + greatGrandChildList[i].ComponentID + ')"/>' + greatGrandChildList[l].ComponentDesc + '</a></div>';
                                }

                                list += '</li></ul>';
                            }
                        }

                        list += '</li></ul>';**
```

I know that I need to make this unobtrusive but any critiques of my JavaScript code as well would be appreciated as I am a noob.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to persist the value of the checkbox. So when you check it your ajax calback needs to update the value of a property. This way when the accordion expands it persists the state of the checkbox.

Comment: I think it is losing state because the click event is also firing the accordion method to expand.

Comment: crocaduck81 - It is firing the according method to expand because of the <a href="#"> instead try this <a href="#" onclick="return false;">

Comment: returning false didn't work, when you say persist state of the checkbox, do you mean store it in a cookie?

Comment: Either store it in a cookie or a server side variable. Something that you can use to figure out what the state of your checkbox is after the accordion expands.

Answer (score 0):

I maintained checkbox state by adding this function

```
        $("a").click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works.

```
$("#accordion h3 input").click(function(event) { 
 event.stopPropagation(); 
});
```